# I'm looking for a cross platform DM to drag and drop files from / to a qemu / kvm Windows guest OS and Ubuntu host os VM

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, desktop-environment, drag-and-drop

Actually I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 as Host OS and Windows 10 as a guest,virtualized with qemu and kvm. No problem at all,but I feel the missing of the possibility to copy and paste files from / to Windows / Linux. I've already configured Samba and I copy and paste files everyday using a shared drive,but this solution is not so comfortable. So,I would ask if someone of you found an ingenious solution to copy and paste files directly from / to the desktop of the two OSes. I suspect that this could be done by mixing different tools in an intelligent way. Maybe using an alternative cross-platform desktop manager or a part of it that's sticked on the main desktop and allows you to drag files without having to open any window each time. Can I install Xorg for Windows 10 ? and above xorg I could install gnome ? or kde ? or a cross platform DE which works under Windows and Linux ? I think that in this way I can drag and drog files because both the DM uses the same protocol and software infrastructure ?

Comment: This has much more to do with file systems than Display mangers imho. KDE used to have a windows port which was discontinued on plasma. Maybe you could do a symlink pointing from the desktop to your shared partition

Comment: ahhh I forgot to say that on the Windows side I have installed the paragon ext4 file system and on the linux side I run the ntfs file system. I think that I haven't any File system problem. right ?

Comment: no man. I want drag and drop files everywhere in the desktop.

Comment: you can symlink a folder to your desktop.

Comment: no. I don't want to do that.

Comment: have you seen this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/819773/is-there-something-like-virtualbox-guest-additions-for-qemu-kvm#851565

Comment: you could switch to VirtualBox and use Guest Additions in the guest OS